# Custom Fonts not working on Appcelerator Titanium SDK 5.3.1

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, custom-font

I am trying to use custom font on my appcelerator android app but it's not working. 
Here is my code.

```
File name = DroidNaskhRegular.ttf
Path = app/assets/android/fonts/DroidNaskhRegular.ttf
// index.tss
"#headertitle":{
    color: "white",
    font:{
           fontFamily: "DroidNaskhRegular"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Path should be this:

**app/assets/fonts/DroidNaskhRegular.ttf**

just move the **fonts** folder out of android.

Comment: To use a custom font in an Alloy project, place the font file in a "fonts" folder inside each platform-specific assets folder.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts

Comment: That's right but sometimes docs are not updated and miss many things.

But you can import a cross-platform app **Employee Directory** from your Dashboard in Studio and there you can see the font used for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could also double check the font name within the TTF itself. I know that iOS and Android treat this differently... in my own app, I updated the TTF to have the same file and font name. You could try opening up the TTF on your computer, see the name (possibly `Droid Arabic Naskh`) and try that as the `fontFamily` instead.

I'm not using Alloy, so my fonts are located in `Resources/iphone/fonts/Whatever.ttf` and `Resources/android/fonts/Whatever.ttf`. I reference them as `font: { fontFamily: 'Whatever' }`.